# How does yyparse *repeatedly* calls yylex?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

> The function produced by Yacc is called yyparse; it is an integer valued function. When it is called, it in turn repeatedly calls yylex, the lexical analyzer supplied by the user (see Section 3) to obtain input tokens.

I can't find a loop that calls yylex inside the c code that yacc geneartes.

How does `yyparse repeatedly calls yylex` process going?

Comment: Finally, [the answer](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~spopuri/cparser.html#yyparse)

Answer (score 0):

Every time the parser needs a token, it calls `yylex`. If your `yacc` is really bison (and probably even if it isn't), there is only one call to `yylex`. The loop around that call is rather large, but it is a loop.